# ./ts_calibrate error : ts_open: No such file or directory

Tags: qt

I have a problem in mini2440. touch screen does not work when my app(Qt application i mean) run on it.
these are my output for " printenv" in mini2440 :

```
[root@FriendlyARM bin]# ./ts_calibrate
ts_open: No such file or directory
[root@FriendlyARM bin]# printenv
TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/usr/local/tslib/lib/ts
USER=root
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Qt/lib:/usr/local/tslib/lib
TSLIB_TSEVENTTYPE=INPUT
OLDPWD=/usr/local/bin
HOME=/
QTDIR=/usr/local/Qt
TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0
PS1=[\u@\h \W]#
TSLIB_PLUGINDIR=/usr/local/tslib/lib/ts
TSLIB_CONSOLEDEVICE=none
LOGNAME=root
TERM=vt102
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
TSLIB_CONFFILE=/usr/local/tslib/etc/ts.conf
SHELL=/bin/sh
QWS_DISPLAY=LinuxFB:mmWidth=105:mmHeight=140
PWD=/usr/local/tslib/bin
QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=tslib:/dev/input/event0
TSLIB_CALIBFILE=/etc/pointercal
```

and in this directory : **/dev/input** => just i have two file : **enevt0 and mice**
in ts.conf : uncomment the first line.
i dont know what is ts_open. where is it? or why show me this error?

i confused :(

Comment: I correct my directory of /tslib/lib/ts(I had mistake).now i have this error :[root@FriendlyARM bin]# ./ts_calibrate 
**Segmentation fault**
WHY MY CALIBRATE (touch) DOSE NOT WORK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ts_open tries to open the file saved in the variable `TSLIB_TSDEVICE`.

`TSLIB_TSDEVICE` must be the device to open to read touch inputs. In your case, it should be `/dev/input/event0`.

Then, ts_calibrate reads the first line in `ts.conf` to get the `module_raw xxx`. Check that your plugin folder (/usr/local/tslib/lib/ts) contains the plugin you give to `module_raw`.

Comment: thanks for reply. this is first line in ts.conf: module_raw input and in /usr/local/tslib/lib/ts there is 2 input. one is input.so the other is input.la. so which one is correct? wht touch not work?

Comment: hi and thx alot to your help. I change my tslib conffile address from /usr/local/tslib/etc/ts.conf to /usr/local/etc/ts.conf and the ./ts_calibrate application run but show me this error show me like: this devise is not tochscreen blah blah blah.. so i change export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/usr/local/tslib/lib/ts to TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event0 . ./ts_calibrate is work. :D but my app touch not work :(

Comment: my application and ./fluidlauncher -qws (from /usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.6.3-arm/demos/ embedded/fluidlauncher/) are the same. both of them has touch screen problem :(   you mean tslib file is wronge? the problem is from the base?this is my tslib :https://github.com/kergoth/tslib

Comment: Well I can't say much without more information about this problem. Is ts_test (in the link I gave you) working? If yes, then maybe you forgot to replace your tslib.so with mine. If it still doesn't work, the problem is probably coming from your application.